# If element visible do action and pass test, else only pass test

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I would like to save number to a file when element is displayed and then test should be passed.
Else if element is not visible test should be also passed but number shoudn't be save into a file.

Saving number when element is displayed works fine, also when element is not displayed test don't save it into file so this also works fine.

Two problems:

1. Selenium search for element when is not displayed approx... 15s? It's too long, how to reduce this time? Use Waits?
2. Most important, if element is not displayed test fails, I'd like to pass it because the whole process is done and waiting for this element and saving number is additional thing.

```
public void saveNumberIntoFile(String fileNumber) throws IOException {

   if(messageInfo.isDisplayed())

{BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\samplefile.txt", true) //Set true for append mode
);
writer.newLine(); //Add new line
writer.write(fileNumber);

writer.close();}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `WebDriverWait` and `ExpectedConditions` to handle wait element, like this:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("")));
```

Replace `By.name("")` with the locator that you initialed on `messageInfo`.

`15` in seconds, if the element is located it will not wait until 15s.

But if within a certain time period that we have determined the element is not found, it will return an error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using....
```

And your test will stop, so you need handle with `try/catch`.

```
public void saveNumberIntoFile(String fileNumber) throws IOException {
    try {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("")));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\samplefile.txt", true) //Set true for append mode
        );
        writer.newLine(); //Add new line
        writer.write(fileNumber);

        writer.close();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied your solution, when element displayed works ok, when not still test fails Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name='//*[@id="ordersummary"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div']"}

Comment: additionally timeout exception added, works fine, thanks!